# Php files won't open

Tags: php, apache-2.2, httpd

I installed everything using powerstack and yum. I've checked over config files and havnt noticed anything. My phpinfo worked once then stopped. http://93.174.91.26/content/serverinfo.php. All other php pages just show up blank or return with error 500. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I'm running the newest versions of everything. I'm on redhat centOS 5

Comment: Any relevant errors in apache log files?

Comment: If I load the page in that link, I get a working `phpinfo()`. DON'T leave that online for any longer than necessary!

Comment: The linked PHPinfo page opens without issue for me. Just an observation (probably unrelated to your problem) - but you seem to be running Apache/PHP as 'root' - not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you try to load one (or more) php extension(s) that is not available, as you are loading a lot of extras there.

You might want to rename your php.ini into php.save and add a file called php.ini w/o any content and restart apache. You can do that like this

```
mv /etc/php.ini /etc/php.save
touch /etc/php.ini
apache2ctl restart
```

Check your page now, if the 500 persists. If that doesn't help,provide some logging output after calling a page of your content. You might want increase the `LogLevel` of your webserver with the highest being `debug`. Search for mentioned directive within your apache configuration.